# Display countdown using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

I want to display countdown in my html page, refreshing the page should not restart the countdown. Can anyone drop any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery.countdown.js

This can be used as

```
 function setCountdown () {

    $('#countdown').countdown({until: +59, format: 'yowdHMS', 
                        layout: '{sn} {sl}', onExpiry: myFunction});
    $('#countdown').removeClass ('is-countdown');
    $('#countdownSpan').show ();
}
```

where the html would be

```
<span id="countdownSpan">&nbsp;<span id="countdown"></span>seconds remaining</span>
```